# How to unperiodise a function

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

We know that given a sufficiently regular function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, then its periodisation (say to period $1$) is given by
$$
\begin{align}
F(x) := \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} f(x + n).\tag{$A$}
\end{align}
$$

Say instead we have a periodic function $F:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ with period 1. Is it possible/is there some procedure by which one can determine the function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that we can write $F$ as $(A)$?

**Example**
For example, if $f : \mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\} \to \mathbb{R}$ is defined as $f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2}$, then we know that
$$
\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}f(x+n) = \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac{1}{(x+n)^2}=\pi^2\csc^2(\pi x)
$$
and thus $F(x) = \pi^2\csc^2(\pi x)$.

Although, what if we only knew $F$ and didn't a-priori know the summation equation relation, is there a procedure to determine $f$?

**NOTE:** Although a method has been described by Piero D'Ancona, it would be interesting to know whether other such methods/procedures exist.

**NOTE 2 (4/7/22):** Following on from the comments of @Nick S, it may be the case that what I am trying to do is perform a localisation in the sense of [*On the Duality of Regular and Local Functions - Jens Fischer*](https://www.mdpi.com/2227-7390/5/3/41).

Comment: $f(x)=F(x) \cdot \chi_{[0,1)}(x)$ works, this is probably not what you are looking for

Comment: @FedorPetrov Thank you for your comment. Yes, I understand one can evaluate in such a way. I have provided an example to be clearer

Comment: Another procedure, which is probably not practical is the following: you can think about $F(x)$ as a function on the Torus $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$. Then, its Fourier transform is a function on $\ZZ$, which is the restriction to $\ZZ$ of $\widehat{f}$. Therefore, given $F$, all you have to do is extend the function $\widehat{F}$ on $\mathbb Z$ to a sufficiently regular function $g=\widehat{f}$ on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @NickS That seems reasonable, although out of curiosity, how would you obtain the behaviour of $\hat{f}$ for values $\xi\not\in\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @spaceman The simplest way is to take the measure $\mu:= \sum_{n \in \mathbb Z} \hat{f}(n) \delta_n$ and convolve it with some nice function $f$ with $f(0)=1$ and $\supp(f) \subseteq (-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2})$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a periodic partition of unity, that is to say a test function $\chi(x)$ such that $\sum \chi(x+n)=1$, and define $f(x)=F(x)\chi(x)$.

In case you are wondering, a periodic partition of unity is easy to build: pick a non negative test function $\psi(x)$ which is strictly positive on $[0,1]$ and zero outside $[-1/2,3/2]$ and define $\chi(x)=\psi(x)/\sum\psi(x+n)$.

Comment: Excellent, thank you

Comment: May be worth noting that $\chi=\chi_{[0,1)}$ recoveres the construction of @Fedor Petrov.